# React & Nodemailer | running server.js file in the cloud

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

I am trying to run a React app with a contact form, that is utilising nodemailer as its back end. However, since the app is running on a very basic hosting, I am not able to open a specific port and therefore want to store the server.js file on a virtual machine in the cloud.

The code is as follows:

**ContactForm.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ContactForm = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("Submit");
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setStatus("Sending...");
    const { name, email, message } = e.target.elements;
    let details = {
      name: name.value,
      email: email.value,
      message: message.value,
    };
    let response = await fetch("http://<vm-IP>:4848/contact", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(details),
    });
    setStatus("Submit");
    let result = await response.json();
    alert(result.status);
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" required />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">{status}</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require("cors");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const form = express();
form.use(cors());
form.use(express.json());
form.use("/", router);
form.listen(4848, () => console.log("Server Running"));

const contactEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
    name: '<provider>',
    host: 'smtp.<provider>.com',
    port: '587',
    auth: {
        user: "<username>",
        pass: "<password>",
    },
});

contactEmail.verify((error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log("Ready to Send");
    }
});

router.post("/contact", (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const message = req.body.message;
    const mail ={
        from: name,
        to: "<target-e-mail>",
        subject: "<subject>",
        html:  `<p>Name: ${name}</p>
                <p>E-mail: ${email}</p>
                <p>Message: ${message}</p>`, 
    };

    contactEmail.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
        if (error) {
            res.json({status: "Error." });
        } else {
            res.json({status: "Message sent." });
        }
    });
});
```

Many thanks.

I have set up the infrastructure, ensured the server.js file was running, but I still cannot seem to get a mail out.

(Apparently, no request ever leaves the website upon pressing the Submit button). Anything I am missing?

Comment: There's a number of issues with what you're trying to do. It's hard to address all of them here (either as comment or answer). First of all you're making cross-server request, which are blocked by browsers unless your server send a proper header back to the browser. Please take a look at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/, using them should give you an idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it. First thing I need to solve, however, is the fact that no request is even made.